# major products of this reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

[image]

My attempt:
polar protic solvent, low temp, tertiary carbon, and a weak (?) nucleophile and a weak base.

It seems like this is a pretty standard SN1 reaction so "I and II" would be the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer is correct as long as you can justify it. (IV) is clearly absurd but why do you eliminate (III) ? However in my opinion at $\ce{20 ^{\circ} C}$ there would be no reaction from a practical point of view, i.e. one with reasonable yield and reaction time.

Comment: 20 C suggests a low temp which favors sn1 over e1 (which would give you III) since e1 has a higher deltaG

Comment: The alcohol is indeed a weak nucleophile. A good general rule of thumb is that an alkoxide (a deprotonated alkyl alcohol such as ethanol or isobutanol) is a much better nucleophile than its alcohol. The $20^{o} C$ is also a good indication for a slow E1 product, as john has said (higher $\Delta G$).


Since the question asks for specifically the major products, I would not include III in the answer. However, if the question had asked for *all* products, III is a possible answer to include. Its mechanism would involve first-order beta elimination due to the sterically-hindered alkyl halide.